# How is the server and client supposed to interact

Tags: javascript

**A little info**

I got my client (localhost:8080) and my server.js (localhost:3000). I made some routes for my `server.js` (see the file below).

**Question**

Now, if I try to access the route on my server e.g. `localhost:3000/users/4`, I get the expected result - 4 fake users are created. However if I try to append the postfix `users/4` to the client: (`localhost:8080/users/4`), I get an error! `Cannot GET /users/4`. Likewise I get an `cannot GET *SOMETHING*` error if I try one of the other routes.

Have I misinterpreted something? Shouldn't I be able to append the route to the client url and then get the res (respons) back again? (as long as the server is running of course, or is that not how it works?)

**routes.js** (I got all my routes in this one file)

```
    var faker = require("faker");

var appRouter = function (app) {


  app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'Welcome to our restful API' });
  });

  app.get("/user", function (req, res) {
    var data = ({
      firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
      lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
      username: faker.internet.userName(),
      email: faker.internet.email()
    });
    res.status(200).send(data);
  });

 app.get("/users/:num", function (req, res) {
   var users = [];
   var num = req.params.num;

   if (isFinite(num) && num  > 0 ) {
     for (i = 0; i <= num-1; i++) {
       users.push({
           firstName: faker.name.firstName(),
           lastName: faker.name.lastName(),
           username: faker.internet.userName(),
           email: faker.internet.email()
        });
     }

     res.status(200).send(users);

   } else {
     res.status(400).send({ message: 'invalid number supplied' });
   }

 });
};

module.exports = appRouter;
```

**Server.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var routes = require("./routes/routes.js");
var app = express();

const server_port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

routes(app);

var server = app.listen(server_port, function () {
    console.log("app running on port.", server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Questions about development are off-topic here, please follow the tour :)

Comment: "my client (localhost:8080)" — Your question doesn't make sense. Clients don't have URLs. It sounds like you have two different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be mixing up something there. When you open `http://localhost:8080/users/4`, then what you are doing is a SERVER request to `localhost:8080` with the route `users/4`. The *client* in your scenario is a browser which is making a request to the server.

Now if your server is actually running on `localhost:3000`, then you must be running *another server* on `localhost:8080`. So if you want to be able to make a request to `http://localhost:8080/users/4`, then you need to configure your server on `localhost:8080` to accept that route, not the one on `localhost:3000`.